# quisiera saber como encender un led cuando se cumpla la condicion if(compareArray(ActualUID,Usuario1))

Tags: arduino, nfc

```
//RST           D9
//SDA(SS)      D10
//MOSI         D11
//MISO         D12
//SCK          D13

#include <SPI.h>
#include <MFRC522.h>

int salida = 7;

#define RST_PIN  9    //Pin 9 para el reset del RC522
#define SS_PIN  10   //Pin 10 para el SS (SDA) del RC522
MFRC522 mfrc522(SS_PIN, RST_PIN); ///Creamos el objeto para el RC522

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600); //Iniciamos La comunicacion serial
  SPI.begin();        //Iniciamos el Bus SPI
  mfrc522.PCD_Init(); // Iniciamos el MFRC522
  Serial.println("Control de acceso:");
  // inicializa el pin Numero = “salida”· (=13) como de salida (output).
  pinMode(salida, OUTPUT);
}

byte ActualUID[4]; //almacenará el código del Tag leído
byte Usuario1[4]= {0xAB, 0x24, 0xEF, 0xC5} ; //código del usuario 1
byte Usuario2[4]= {0xC1, 0x2F, 0xD6, 0x0E} ; //código del usuario 2
void loop() {
  // Revisamos si hay nuevas tarjetas  presentes
  if ( mfrc522.PICC_IsNewCardPresent()) 
        {  
      //Seleccionamos una tarjeta
            if ( mfrc522.PICC_ReadCardSerial()) 
            {
                  // Enviamos serialemente su UID
                  Serial.print(F("Card UID:"));
                  for (byte i = 0; i < mfrc522.uid.size; i++) {
                          Serial.print(mfrc522.uid.uidByte[i] < 0x10 ? " 0" : " ");
                          Serial.print(mfrc522.uid.uidByte[i], HEX);   
                          ActualUID[i]=mfrc522.uid.uidByte[i];          
                  } 
                  Serial.print("     ");                 
                  //comparamos los UID para determinar si es uno de nuestros usuarios  
                  if(compareArray(ActualUID,Usuario1))
                    Serial.println("Acceso concedido...");



                  else if(compareArray(ActualUID,Usuario2))
                    Serial.println("Acceso concedido...");
                  else
                    Serial.println("Acceso denegado...");

                  // Terminamos la lectura de la tarjeta tarjeta  actual
                  mfrc522.PICC_HaltA();

            }


  }

}

//Función para comparar dos vectores
 boolean compareArray(byte array1[],byte array2[])
{
  if(array1[0] != array2[0])return(false);
  if(array1[1] != array2[1])return(false);
  if(array1[2] != array2[2])return(false);
  if(array1[3] != array2[3])return(false);
  return(true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

imagino que la variable salida que tienes allí es para el pin (13) del LED. Teniendo en cuenta esto solo es agregar dentro del if:

```
digitalWrite(salida , HIGH);   // poner el Pin en HIGH
delay(1000);                   // esperar un segundo porque la verificación es tan rapida que puede que no se note mucho el encendido
digitalWrite(salida , LOW);    //Luego lo apagas una vez el led le confirma que ha sido aceptado.
```

Espero te sirva.